# Spring Java Configuration Error - HTTP 500 error

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

So I switched from using web.xml in Spring 4 to using Java based configuration.  I was able to deploy my WAR file fine, but received this when I went to the page:

[image]

Here are my Java config files:

**SpringWebAppInitializer.java**

```
package melon.melon.config;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration;

import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class SpringWebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext appContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        appContext.register(ApplicationContextConfig.class);

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet(
                "SpringDispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(appContext));
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/");

    }
}
```

**ApplicationContextConfig.java**

```
package melon.melon.config;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import melon.melon.dao.UserDAO;
import melon.melon.dao.UserDAOImpl;
import melon.melon.model.User;

import org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("melon.melon")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class ApplicationContextConfig {
    // @Bean configurations go here...
    @Bean(name = "viewResolver")
    public InternalResourceViewResolver getViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        return viewResolver;
    }

    @Bean(name = "dataSource")
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://domain:3306/usersdb");
        dataSource.setUsername("root");
        dataSource.setPassword("pass");

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Autowired
    @Bean(name = "sessionFactory")
    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory(DataSource dataSource) {

        LocalSessionFactoryBuilder sessionBuilder = new LocalSessionFactoryBuilder(dataSource);

        sessionBuilder.addAnnotatedClasses(User.class);
        sessionBuilder.addProperties(getHibernateProperties());

        return sessionBuilder.buildSessionFactory();
    }

    private Properties getHibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
        return properties;
    }

    @Autowired
    @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
    public HibernateTransactionManager getTransactionManager(
            SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager(
                sessionFactory);

        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Autowired
    @Bean(name = "userDao")
    public UserDAO getUserDao(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        return new UserDAOImpl(sessionFactory);
    }
}
```

Any ideas as to what's going wrong?

Comment: There is at least a `@EnableWebMvc` annotation missing, next your `getHibernateProperties` method isn't used so the properties are ignored. Another tip instead of specifying all the `name` attributes just rename your methods, those will be used as bean names/ids.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Where could I call `getHibernateProperties`, and which of the two classes would  `@EnableWebMvc` go in?

Comment: I assume you have those properties to configure hibernate, currently they are doing nothing. You want to inject them into your `LocalSessionFactoryBuilder`. The `@EnableWebMvc` should go on the configuration class.

Comment: Building up on what M. Deinum said, you should add it to ApplicationContextConfig or your WebApplicationConfig (if you have one). Also don't make the same mistake i did and leave the xml files around to be picked up, they are made redundant for most part.

Comment: Hi guys.  Thanks for your advice, I added the `@EnableWebMvc` annotation to `SpringWebAppInitializer.java` and called `getHibernateProperties()` in my `getSessionFactory` method.  However, I'm still getting the above error when building the project into a WAR and deploying it.  Any ideas?